# Multiple controllers with same name

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to have multiple controllers with the same name, on different paths. For example:

```
/abc/security/login
/xyz/security/login
```

This leads to 404 error. When removing the duplicate controller, the error is gone.

I have setup attribute routing like so:

```
namespace Controllers.Abc
{
    [RoutePrefix("abc/security")]
    public class SecurityController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequestModel requestModel)
        {

namespace Controllers.Xyz
{
    [RoutePrefix("xyz/security")]
    public class SecurityController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginRequestModel requestModel)
        {
```

This is .NET Framework Web Api.

Comment: Is your Register method being called in your Global.asax's applicationstart method (assuming this is not OWIN)?

Comment: Yes, `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

Comment: When you say multiple controllers with the same name, do you mean two different `SecurityController`'s that are in different namespaces?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have.

Comment: You should take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933731/ambiguous-controller-names-with-routing-attributes-controllers-with-same-name-a). It looks like you'll need a custom implementation of `IHttpControllerSelector` to handle this use case.

Comment: Your requirement  is very similar to [API Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42373994/296861).

Comment: Thank you, Win, it is perfect.